# Can you use several PHP editor (using Cakephp ) at the same time on Wamp - like Komodo, Eclipse, Aptana

Tags: php, eclipse, cakephp, aptana, komodo

Can you use several PHP editor (using Cakephp ) at the same time on Wamp - like Komodo, Eclipse, Aptana

- how should you set the settings if using different editors at the same time
- to what folder the web projects should belong - on wamp folders somewhere ?
- are there any problems if trying to use multiple editors , degugging, cakephp editor plugin integration or other problems if using several IDE-s at the same time

Comment: Theoretically yes, it is possible. In practice it would be a pain in the back end.

Comment: Why would you want to use multiple editors at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have six hands, I'm assuming you want several people to be able to edit source with different editors.

Of course you can do this - even if you do have six hands. I'm currently using Netbeans, Eclipse & Dreamweaver to edit stuff at work and Netbeans, Eclipse, Textmate and Textwrangler at home. No problems.

Normally, these IDEs will keep the config info in your home folder and the project data in the source folder. Not an issue because Netbeans will ignore Eclipse etc.

Likely problems are:

- auto formatting may differ between IDEs (tabs, how to format code blocks etc.)
- the possibility of several people working on the same file. This will happen whether you use different editors or not. Use something like [Git](http://git-scm.com/) or [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) to manage the source code .
- They take up a lot of disk space.
- If you're using them at the same time on the same machine, they'll all want to grab all of the memory.

Wamp doesn't care what you do - it has no knowledge of the editors.

It's easiest to keep your projects in the htdocs folder of WAMP. This may be called WWW or Documents or Htdocs depending on your setup.

The editor plugins are editor dependent. Komodo won't care what plugins Eclipse has etc.

Of the IDEs you mention, I prefer the one you haven't - Netbeans. It's less bloaty than Eclipse. I used Komodo for a while, but Netbeans is just better.

Now I have to use Eclipse because I'm programming Coldfusion at work and Android at home. Netbeans won't do CF and struggles with Android.

Comment: how do you do version control with netbeans and can you well with cakephp with netbeans

Comment: Here tells you how to set up Netbeans for CakePHP: http://www.tiplite.com/cakephp-debug-in-netbeans/

Comment: Sun/Oracle are developing a plugin for Git for NB: http://nbgit.org/ but I tend to do it all at the cli.